# How to fix, AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning:

Tags: java, minecraft

So I am kind of a noob at java and I am trying to make a Minecraft mod I don't know what happened because in eclipse when I run Minecraft it goes through the forge loading screen and it gets up to 7 and looks like its going to complete but then crashes and shows these error messages ([full log](https://pastebin.com/q8jNVUx5)):

```
[21:26:28] [main/WARN] [FML]: Registry Item: Override did not have an associated owner object. Name: mcadditions:netherinium_sword Value: superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.items.tools.ToolSword@67127bb1
[21:26:28] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:629]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I blame Dinnerbone.

Time: 9/14/19 9:26 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.RuntimeException: One of more entry values did not copy to the correct id. Check log for details!
    at net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistry.sync(ForgeRegistry.java:555)
```

The only thing I have found that fixes it is if I delete my file called RegistryHandler which shows

```
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.ModelRegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventBusSubscriber;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.init.ModItems;
import superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.util.IHasModel;

@EventBusSubscriber
public class RegistryHandler 
{

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onItemRegisterer(RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event)
    {

        event.getRegistry().registerAll(ModItems.ITEMS.toArray(new Item[0]));
    }

        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onModelRegister(ModelRegistryEvent event)
        {

            for(Item item : ModItems.ITEMS)
            {

                if(item instanceof IHasModel)
                {

                    ((IHasModel)item).registerModels();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Also, here's my ToolSword.java:

```
package superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.items.tools;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSword;
import superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.Main;
import superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.init.ModItems;
import superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.util.IHasModel;

public class ToolSword extends ItemSword implements IHasModel {

    public ToolSword(String name, ToolMaterial material)
    {
        super(material);
        setUnlocalizedName(name);
        setRegistryName(name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.TOOLS);

        ModItems.ITEMS.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerModels()
    {
        Main.proxy.registerItemRenderer(this, 0, "inventory");
    }

}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
    public static final ItemSword NETHERINIUM_SWORD = new ToolSword("netherinium_sword", MATERIAL_NETHERINIUM);
```

But when I do this and I go into my Minecraft world it says that some registry thing got deleted which causes all my blocks and items to dissapear

Comment: What you posted as the error isn't the actual error. It's just normal warnings from Minecraft shutting down. The actual error will be before it, and it's what we'd need to help you fix the problem.

Comment: ```21:11:21] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Holder lookups applied
[21:11:21] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: The state engine was in incorrect state SERVER_STARTING and forced into state SERVER_STOPPED. Errors may have been discarded.
[21:11:25] [main/INFO] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Stopping!
[21:11:25] [main/INFO] [minecraft/SoundManager]: SoundSystem shutting down...
[21:11:25] [main/WARN] [minecraft/SoundManager]: Author: Paul Lamb, www.paulscode.com
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release```

Comment: This is what is says before how can I fix this?

Comment: That's still not enough. Look for a stack trace.

Comment: Where do I find stack trace it is my first time

Comment: here is the paste bin of the full crash

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4pFBBdpy

Comment: Your logs contradict what you say happens. You say "it gets up to 7 and looks like its going to complete but then crashes", but your log indicates that it successfully got past 7 and to the main menu, then you loaded a saved game, and then it shut down.

Comment: sorry I might of put the wrong crash because I started the game again without the Registry Handler im going to put the real crash in the paste bin

Comment: It gets to about 6 and then crashes and this shows https://pastebin.com/q8jNVUx5

Comment: `[21:26:28] [main/WARN] [FML]: Registry Item: Override did not have an associated owner object. Name: mcadditions:netherinium_sword Value: superrobbie10.MinecraftAdditions.items.tools.ToolSword@67127bb1` That's the important bit. Please post the code related to that item.

Comment: Here is all the code to the sword I also copied the ToolSword for my shovel but renamed ToolSpade

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TJS6PwJk

Comment: See also [Code Style #3](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/61757-common-issues-and-recommendations/?tab=comments#comment-289567) and [Problematic Code #14](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/61757-common-issues-and-recommendations/?tab=comments#comment-289566). That second one is why things broke. The first one is just stupid boilerplate that does nothing but make you write more code to do something you could have done anyway.

Comment: I don't know what that means but im an idiot somehow two times in a row because i rewrote all my code and in my tool tab I had the values and stuff as                                                                                                             public static final ItemSword NETHERINIUM_SWORD = new ToolSword("netherinium_sword", MATERIAL_NETHERINIUM);                                                                                 public static final ItemSpade NETHERINIUM_SHOVEL = new ToolSpade("NETHERINIUM_SWORD", MATERIAL_NETHERINIUM); 
} so I had the shovel as NETHERINIUM_SWORD

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the problem:

```
    setUnlocalizedName(name);
    setRegistryName(name);
```

There, `name` is `"netherinium_sword"`. Your unlocalized name and registry name aren't supposed to be the same, as your registry name needs to be namespaced. Try this instead:

```
    setUnlocalizedName(name);
    setRegistryName("mcadditions:" + name);
```

(Or if you have a constant with your mod ID, you can use it instead of hardcoding.)

Comment: I experimented with this and tried some other things but im still getting a crash here is what I did (changed it to the same thing as you) and my crash report https://pastebin.com/TKst0rth

Comment: If this helps im following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9tVl1vmMU4&t=121s and the guys code is still working without changing the name? did I mess up another code?

Comment: Im going to rewrite the code over again Im pretty sure I just messed up